# apportable unarchiveObjectWithData with error strcmp()

Tags: ios, apportable

When called:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dictData];


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x400c6844 in strcmp ()
from /Users/myname/.apportable/cache/devices/4dfcdd3168ea50fb/libs/libc.so
```

Is there a bug of apportable libs?

Test Code:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,16)],@"Archive_Version",[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(16,0)],@"Clothes.txt",nil];

NSData *dictData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];

[dictionary release];

NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dictData];
```

I use free version of Apportable, When I debug in console, the result is:

(gdb) po dictionary
{Archive_Version = "{location=0, length=16}"; Clothes.txt = "{location=16, length=0}"; }

(gdb) po dict2
{Archive_Version = "{location=-284, length=1588768934}"; Clothes.txt = "{location=7, length=1593147632}"; }

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug with NSArchiver that will be fixed in an upcoming refactor of foundation.  Check out https://code.google.com/p/apportable/ for known bug reports.